# How do I enable ADC_1 interrupt in STM32 Microcontroller

Tags: stm32, interrupt-handling, keil, adc

How do I enable ADC_1 interrupt in NVIC without using any library, in STM32F103RB microcontroller?

I am using keil uvision4.

Answer (score 0):

The hardcore version:

```
*((volatile uint32_t *)((0xE000E000UL) +  0x0100UL)) = (uint32_t)(1UL << (((uint32_t)(int32_t)18) & 0x1FUL));
```